# Display block not showing back after set to none

Tags: html, css

I have the following menu design

```
<div class="span2 main-menu-span">
    <div class="well nav-collapse sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu">
            <li class="nav-header hidden-tablet"><span id="menu1" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" onClick=checkMenu('menu1')>-</span> Main 1</li>
            <li id='menu1a'><a class="ajax-link" href="menu1a.php"><span class="hidden-tablet">Menu 1 a</span></a></li>
            <li id='menu1b'><a class="ajax-link" href="menu1b.php"><span class="hidden-tablet">Menu 1 b</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do it that when the user press the '-' symbol it get it hidden and the symbol change to '+' but then I press it never appear back.

```
function checkMenu(idVal){
   var idValue = idVal;
   //alert("Mwnu value :" +idValue);
   //alert("Mwnu value :" +document.getElementById(idValue).innerHTML);
   if(document.getElementById(idValue).innerHTML=="+"){
      if(idValue == "menu1" ){
        //alert("Mwnu value :" +idValue);
        document.getElementById("menu1a").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("menu1b").style.display="block";            
        document.getElementById("menu1").innerHTML ="-" ;
      }         
   }
   if(document.getElementById(idValue).innerHTML=="-"){
      if(idValue=="menu1"){             
        //alert("Mwnu value :" +document.getElementById("menu1a").style.display);
        document.getElementById("menu1a").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("menu1b").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("menu1").innerHTML ="+" ;
      }         
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `else if`:

```
else if(document.getElementById(idValue).innerHTML=="-")
{
...
```

Comment: Thank it was a logic error on my side. Any I got more menu coming below can I make the names dynamic where the main menu will be menu1 follow by the child menu so that I dont need to write long if and else if

Comment: Yes, I would highly recommend using a pattern that does not require copy-paste. As a general rule, whenever you find yourself doing a copy-paste and then changing particular items in the lines you have pasted, you should be using a function and a loop instead.

Comment: Any idea on how to do that I am quite new to this? Any hint or help please

Comment: I would recommend asking a separate question here on SO since this first question of yours has been resolved. Makes things a little easier :)

Comment: Ok thank just that I need to change rite? Anything else please?

Comment: I don't see anything else in the code you posted that needs addressing right now except perhaps to cache your references to `document.getElementById("menu1b")` like by doing `var menu1b = document.getElementById("menu1b")` and then using `menu1b`. Highly recommend posting a second question regarding how to structure your code in a way that avoids copy-paste. Post a link to that question here and then I'll attempt to answer it so that we can avoid having a cascade of questions here.

Answer (score 1):

as you see in the alert, the value of the innerHtml has spaces, use trim(), plus else if as JoshJ said

```
document.getElementById(idValue).innerHTML.trim()
```

viz: http://plnkr.co/edit/YPE59IR4GKxL4JCilNUz?p=preview

EDIT:
BTW, unless you want to learn this, I would recommend using something like bootstrap, where those things are already done for you.